# Set default text in a text field for a form

Tags: javascript, css

I am making a form where almost every person filling out the form will be from the same city, state and zip code. Is there anyway I can have default text in the text area that will count when it sends? I have seen forms where there is text in the text area, but when the user clicks on the field the text disappears. I would not want the text to disappear on field click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a sample form with "default" inputs in the text box

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
 First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Doe"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

The thing to add is `value="something here"`

In this example the input boxes has John and Doe **written** not there as a **placeholder**

As you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_value) at w3school

If you are useing a text area then you can do something like this:

```
<textarea name='someName'>Default value</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

whatever you write between the tag is the default value for the textarea

```
<textarea id="txtarea">This is the Default Value</textarea>
```

This is different for `input type=text`. In that case you need to use the value attribute